# Reset input field after record save

Tags: hibernate, jsf

I want to clear the input text fields after the record save. But the values remains. How can I clear the values of the text fields of the form? plz help thanks in advance.
my sponsor.xhtml is

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head>
   <style type="text/css">
            .ui-growl{
                left:20px;
            }
        </style>

</h:head>
<body>
    <ui:composition template="#{localeControllerBean.path}">
    <ui:define name="head">
        <style>.ui-growl{ #{msg['msg']}: 20px; }</style>
        </ui:define>
        <ui:define name="content">

            <h:form enctype="multipart/form-data" dir="#{localeControllerBean.direction}" id="form1">
                <div id="add">
                <p:growl  id="msgs" autoUpdate="true" display="icon" style="left:20px"></p:growl>

                </div>
                <p:panel header="#{msg['sponsor_detail']}" style="font-size:small">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <f:event listener="#{localeControllerBean.islang}" type="preRenderView" />

                        <p:outputLabel for="sname" value="#{msg['sponsor_name']}"
                            styleClass="label" />
                        <p:inputText id="sname" value="#{sponsorBean.sponsor_name}"
                            required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['sponsor_name_msg']}"
                            styleClass="input">
                            <f:validator validatorId="sponsorValidator" />
                        </p:inputText>

                        <p:outputLabel for="sadd" value="#{msg['sponsoraddress']}:"
                            styleClass="label" />
                        <p:inputText id="sadd" value="#{sponsorBean.s_address}"
                            required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['Sponsor_address_msg']}"
                            styleClass="input" />

                        <p:outputLabel for="smb" value="#{msg['sponsor_mbno']}:"
                            styleClass="label" />
                        <p:inputText id="smb" value="#{sponsorBean.s_mobile_no}"
                            required="true" requiredMessage="#{msg['sponsor_mbno_msg']}"
                            styleClass="input" />

                        <p:outputLabel for="ss" value="#{msg['sponsor_status']}:" styleClass="label" />
                        <p:inputText id="ss" value="#{sponsorBean.status}" required="true"
                            requiredMessage="#{msg['sponsor_mbno_msg']}" styleClass="input" />
                    </h:panelGrid>

                    <h:panelGrid columns="2" cellpadding="8" style="margin-left:6%">
                    <p:commandButton id="submit" value="#{msg['save']}" ajax="false"
                        action="#{sponsorBean.save}"  style=""
                        update="msgs" icon="ui-icon-disk"/>

                    <p:commandButton type="reset" value="#{msg['reset']}"
                        style="" ajax="false" icon="ui-icon-arrowrefresh-1-e" actionListener="#{sponsorBean.reset}/>
 </h:panelGrid>
                </p:panel>
            </h:form>
        </ui:define>
    </ui:composition>
</body>
</html>
```

and sponsorbeam.java file is

```
package com.pms.main;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import org.primefaces.event.ColumnResizeEvent;
import pojo.TblSponsor;
import com.pms.hmb.Tbl_company;
import com.pms.hmb.Tbl_companydocs;
import com.pms.hmb.Tbl_employee;
import com.pms.hmb.Tbl_sponsor;
import com.pms.util.HibernateUtil;
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class SponsorBean {
    private int s_id;
    private String sponsor_name;
    private String s_address;
    private String s_mobile_no;
    private String status;
    private Set<Tbl_company> tbl_companies=null;
    Tbl_sponsor selectsponsor=new Tbl_sponsor();

 public Set<Tbl_company> getTbl_companies() {
        return tbl_companies;
    }
    public void setTbl_companies(Set<Tbl_company> tbl_companies) {
        this.tbl_companies = tbl_companies;
    }





    public Tbl_sponsor getSelectsponsor() {
        return selectsponsor;
    }
    public void setSelectsponsor(Tbl_sponsor selectsponsor) {
        this.selectsponsor = selectsponsor;
    }
    public int getS_id() {
        return s_id;
    }
    public void setS_id(int s_id) {
        this.s_id = s_id;
    }
    public String getSponsor_name() {
        return sponsor_name;
    }
    public void setSponsor_name(String sponsor_name) {
        this.sponsor_name = sponsor_name;
    }
    public String getS_address() {
        return s_address;
    }
    public void setS_address(String s_address) {
        this.s_address = s_address;
    }
    public String getS_mobile_no() {
        return s_mobile_no;
    }
    public void setS_mobile_no(String s_mobile_no) {
        this.s_mobile_no = s_mobile_no;
    }
    public String getStatus() {
        return status;
    }
    public void setStatus(String status) {
        this.status = status;

    }



    public void onResize(ColumnResizeEvent event) {  
        FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage("Column " + event.getColumn().getClientId() + " resized", "W:" + event.getWidth() + ", H:" + event.getHeight());  

        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, msg);  
    }  

    public String save()
    {
    Tbl_sponsor tbl_sponsor=new Tbl_sponsor();
    tbl_sponsor.setName(this.sponsor_name);
    tbl_sponsor.setS_address(s_address);
    tbl_sponsor.setS_mobile_no(s_mobile_no);
    tbl_sponsor.setStatus(status);

//      tbl_company.setComapany(tbl_company);
        Tbl_company tbl_company1=new Tbl_company();
//      tbl_company1.setComapnyname("a");
//      tbl_company1.setAddress("b");
//      tbl_company1.setEmail("c");
//      tbl_company1.setMobileNumber("66");
//      tbl_company1.setLogoAlt(name);
//      tbl_company1.setImageType(type);
//      tbl_company1.setLogo(byteslogo);
//      tbl_company1.setEmail(email);
//      tbl_company1.setComapany(tbl_company1);
//      tbl_company.setComapany(null);
//tbl_company.setComapany(tbl_company1);

//  tbl_company.setTbl_companies(tbl_company);
        Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction tx = null;

        try {
            tx = session.beginTransaction();
            session.save(tbl_company1);
            session.save(tbl_sponsor);

//          session.save(tblemployee);
//          session.save(tblikama);
            tx.commit();
            FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
            String value = context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{msg['sponsor_added']}", String.class);

            context.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage(value));

        }
        catch(ConstraintViolationException e)
        {
//  logger.error("error code 409 while creating employee:Constraintvoilation Exception:"+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
//          logger.error("error code 500 while creating employee: Exception:"+e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();


        }
        finally
        {

            session.close();

        }

        return "";
    }
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

@SessionScoped beans stores its data through a user session, that is why values of session data members are seen in the page.

Data members should be set to their default values in the action method so that submited values will not be seen in the page again.

```
this.s_id = 0;
this.sponsor_name = null;
this.s_address = null;
this.s_mobile_no = null;
this.status = null;
return "";
```

Or you can change scope of managed bean to `@RequestScoped`. `@RequestScoped` beans are created from starch for each request.

Furthermore, accessing database in managed beans is not a good practice. You should separate data access from managed beans for the principle  [low coupling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coupling_%28computer_programming%29) [high cohesion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohesion_%28computer_science%29)

**See also**

[DAO tutorial - the data layer](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2008/07/dao-tutorial-data-layer.html)

Answer (score -1):

Try to clear all `String` fields of `SponsorBean` object after saving:

At the end of `save` method:

```
    ...
    this.sponsor_name = null;
    this.s_address = null;
    this.s_mobile_no = null;
    return "";
}
```

Did you consider using request or conversation scoped beans instead of session scoped? They might solve your problem.

Comment: Why empty strings instead of null?

Comment: @BalusC no reason. Yes, setting to null makes more sense.